# kafka connect hdfs flatten array records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are experimenting with Kafka Connect HDFS and have source data which contains an array of avro records (referred to as container record below) which are pushed to topics.

The plan was to use kafka-connect hdfs to flatten the array in the container record into individual records and write to hdfs as avro and then commit the actual container record.

However it seems that kafka-connect-hdfs does not support this out of the box.
In attempt to navigate the source we found that there is a tight mapping of the topic names and offset management and attempting to transform 1 sinkRecod to multiple sinkRecords deviates from expected behavior.

so wanted to verify if 1 to n transformation possible ? if so how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Connect supports Single Message Transforms (SMT) which is the area of functionality, if any, in Kafka Connect that would do what you want. However IIRC SMT are only for 1:1 input/output record processing, not 1:n - that is, I don't *think* (but am willing to be corrected) that you can generate additional output records from a single input record.

You probably want to look at Kafka Streams which would give you the full capabilities of doing this. You'd write a streams app which would subscribe to the source topic, do the necessary array processing, and write it back to a new Kafka topic. The new Kafka topic would then be the source topic for your Kafka Connect HDFS sink.